# Are there helper classes that implement logical operations on boolean collections in any of the standard libraries?

Tags: java, collections, boolean, guava

I concocted this little helper class, and wanted to know if there's anywhere I can steal it from instead of re-implementing the wheel:

```
public class Booleans3 {
    private Booleans3(){}

    public static boolean and(Iterable<Boolean> booleans) {
        boolean result = true;
        for (Boolean boolRef : booleans) {
            boolean bool = boolRef;
            result &= bool;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static boolean or(Iterable<Boolean> booleans) {
        boolean result = false;
        for (Boolean boolRef : booleans) {
            boolean bool = boolRef;
            result |= bool;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I looked at [com.google.common.primitives.Booleans](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Booleans.html), and it doesn't seem to contain what I need.

Comment: What happened to `Booleans1` and `Booleans2`? ;)

Comment: i never thought of doing this :D

Comment: @Nailuj - I have a weird little convention of naming helper libraries `Something3`. This is after various companies invented `Collections` and `Collections2`.

Comment: @ripper234: I see a potential flaw in your logic. Just wait till the day some company creates `Collections3`, then you're screwed big time! If I were you, I'd go for `Something4325` instead, that should at least keep you safe for some years ;)

Comment: @Nailuj - I should actually go for `Something234` to match my username :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this:

```
public static boolean and(Collection<Boolean> booleans)
{
    return !booleans.contains(Boolean.FALSE);
}

public static boolean or(Collection<Boolean> booleans)
{
    return booleans.contains(Boolean.TRUE);
}
```

Comment: I'm accepting @templatetypedef's answer because it performs better (negligible, but still) - but I do like your solution!

Comment: @ripper234: Just out of curiosity: how can you conclude that templatetypedef's answer performs better? Now this is only guessing, but I would think that the implementation behind `Collection<T>.Contains()` actually _would_ break on the first hit, and thus be (at least) as efficient as templatetypedef's... Or am I completely off here?

Comment: @Nailuj - wait a sec ... right you are, sry, I wasn't thinking. Accepted!

Answer (score 2):

While @eng-fouad answer is good enough I still suggest another one which utilizes [Iterables.all()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#all%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) and [Iterables.any()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#any%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) with [equalTo](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html#equalTo%28T%29) predicate:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import static java.lang.Boolean.FALSE;
import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;

import static com.google.common.collect.Iterables.all;
import static com.google.common.collect.Iterables.any;
import static com.google.common.base.Predicates.equalTo;

...

Iterable<Boolean> booleans = Arrays.asList(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE);

System.out.println(all(booleans, equalTo(TRUE)));
System.out.println(any(booleans, equalTo(TRUE)));
```

will print

```
false
true
```

As pluses I see:

- Uses Guava library
- No need to write own class with methods
- Better readability (IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is any part of the Java Standard Libraries that provides exactly this functionality.

In some languages, these are provided as functions called `anyOf` (for `or`) or `allOf` (for `and`).  You may have some luck searching for Java libraries implementing those functions.

A note-, the code you have here can be optimized quite a bit.  Note that if you're computing the AND of many boolean values, as soon as you find a `false` value you can stop and say that the answer is `false`.  Similarly, if you're computing the OR of boolean values, you can stop as soon as you find a `true` value, since the answer will be `true`.  This is essentially a generalization of [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) to lists of objects, and is the behavior of some versions of `and` and `or` in languages like Scheme.  This gives the following:

```
public class ModifiedBooleans3 {
    private ModifiedBooleans3(){}

    public static boolean and(Iterable<Boolean> booleans) {
        for (Boolean boolRef : booleans)
            if (!boolRef)
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean or(Iterable<Boolean> booleans) {
        for (Boolean boolRef : booleans)
            if (boolRef)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

## An Improvement on `@Eng.Fouad` answer:

The following code return `false` if `boolean` collection is `null` or `empty`, otherwise do logical operation on elements:

```
public static boolean and(Collection<Boolean> booleans) {
    return booleans != null && !booleans.isEmpty() && !booleans.contains(Boolean.FALSE);
}

public static boolean or(Collection<Boolean> booleans) {
    return booleans != null && !booleans.isEmpty() && booleans.contains(Boolean.TRUE);
}
```